# Python only reading the first line of CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm sure this is simple, but it's driving me nuts.
Code only reads the first line of the CSV file. 
If I enter the name at the top of the CSV it asks for the password. If I enter any of the others in the list it goes to 'You are not currently registered'. 
I can't figure out why?

```
with open('members.csv', 'r') as mem_login:
    login_reader = csv.reader(mem_login)
    for row in login_reader:
        if member in row:
            password = input('Please enter password...  ').lower()
            if password in row:
                print('Welcome ' + member.capitalize() + ', login successful!')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            reg_now = input('You are not currently registered. Would you like to sign-up now? Y or N   ').lower()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv file you are using ?

Comment: I hope you're not going to implement a user database like this! :)

Comment: Can you explain why you expected the code *not* to behave like you described? And what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @najeem: What? You're telling me there is something wrong with storing passwords in plaintext?!? (also, strangely, in lowercase only, and with no ability to reenter the password if you typo it even once, and also, user names are valid if they appear as passwords, and vice-versa, so every user name is its own password too) What will they think of next?

Comment: @najeem no, this is just practice code.

Comment: @Paul it's just a basic csv file with 2 columns. First for usernames, second for passwords.

Comment: @mkrieger I thought it would iterate through the rows and only go to the else is it doesn't find it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` case is attached to `if member in row:`, so if the first `row` doesn't contain the `member`, you immediately assume they're unregistered. Dedent it a line to attach it to the `for` loop, so the `else` block only fires if the `for` loop runs to completion without `break`ing:

```
# newline='' is mandatory for csv module to handle dialect's newline conventions
# mode defaults to 'r', so you don't need to use it
with open('members.csv', newline='') as mem_login:
    # Unpack to username and userpass, and test individually, 
    # so user names are not their own passwords
    for username, userpass in csv.reader(mem_login): # One-lined creation of reader since it's only needed for loop
        if member == username:
            password = input('Please enter password...  ').lower()
            if password == userpass:
                print('Welcome ' + member.capitalize() + ', login successful!')
                break  # break bypasses the for's else block
    else:
        # Only runs if break not executed
        reg_now = input('You are not currently registered. Would you like to sign-up now? Y or N   ').lower()
```

I made few other small fixes/improvements (all commented), but the big change is the dedent of the `else` block to attach it to the `for` loop, not the `if`.

Note: Even with my changes, this has serious flaws (caseless passwords, passwords in plaintext), so never use it for real user authentication.

Comment: it's only finding the first row

Comment: @totaln00b: Did you actually dedent the `else` block? Because it will in fact test the whole file, row by row, if you did. Whether the rest of the file is correctly formatted, I can't say; you didn't provide useful inputs.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos: It works just fine if the inputs match (and `member` is a string matching a user name in the file): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFLT8MwDL73V5hTWlEibdyQpp25ABKHaacpa93OWppUeVCNP1@cwF7CJyv294rHUzhY8zzPNIzWBWj8Vw1ki04dsSONsAIhRPToFvWovF8UqV/mflnwqBhw2KNLe3kiionCgSnkZ3Bk@tf38sxVgfLA6zttezIvBXB11kHCGTVgnbvEDGSSE@lQtejKC6b6BaWiDs7KqwvDdZwqMU3WteyNzBhDKT40Ko@AJjDuPJZSAohKajuxVnVHwSpXltXF371O1uKsLLBB3dgBQcDjnz3ZqJGC0vSNZcWvooYcBXxsGvS@i/pBVP/49hz9mF9R@5tcDvudsdM10tZGUA7BWD5edI6z6VNaI88hsZWwsVG3cOI9TUeEYMFTb57iyJhpDVvgE7zB7RfMcz7vDw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ShadowRanger it's working now thank you. It was the indentation on the else. Your code worked. Thanks.